# Alternative way to use break when using case in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is there an alternative way to skip the "break" in every case and just imply that when the case with the same value is found to just break.

```
int w=3;
switch (w)
{
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("3p");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("4");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("csd");
        break;
}
```

Comment: See [switch expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325).

Comment: Is adding `break` causing you some pain?

Comment: You might refactor your switch() in its own method and e.g. `return "3p";`, no `break;` required.

Comment: @f_puras - That may be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: I don't think you understand exactly what it is that 'break' does here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am having an idea of what you are looking for: I try to avoid repeating the `case` and `println()` values.

```
int w = 3;

switch (w) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 4:
        System.out.println(w);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("3p");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("csd");
        break;
}
```

This way you only handle cases explicitely in which the desired output does not match the value of `w`.

Comment: The question was experimental, I wanted to see if there were any interesting ways to do common tasks. Your answer suggests that you know that the cases:1,2,4 are useless, would this be known in a real implementation or it explores something that would not be of use? I mean putting in a group as you did is the same as omitting them altogether. Correct me if I'm wrong but doing something that will handle the situation in an unknown event of a case that will match the initial "w" would be the optimal solution. Thanks

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I explained my idea right: Cases 1, 2, and 4 are in no way omitted. In fact, my code is supposed to behave in exact the same way as yours does. By handling the mentioned cases together, I express the implicit rule "if w is 1, 2, or 4 then just output w". And as the `default` case is already assigned to some other behaviour, we cannot use it without breaking the current code'e logic. We cannot know which other values of `w` might occur.

Comment: BTW: Aren't questions always experimental? In any case, you might want to check if any of the answers here - and there are good ones among them - is sufficiently good enough for you to accept it.

Comment: I think you are close, I meant you grouped 1,2,4 together because you knew that they are not equal to "w". If the value w comes from user's input for example how would you prepare for that?

Comment: Well, not quite. I took your assignment of `w` as an example for a possible value. If I could rely on `w == 3`, then the whole code would be just `System.out.println("3p");`, unconditionally. Maybe you should try running the code with different values for `w` and check its outcome...

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

No, `break` isn't optional unless you want to fall through to the next `case` label. (Well, unless you `return` or `throw` from the `case`.) But keep reading...

If you want to avoid writing the `break`s, you can use an `if`/`else if`/`else` structure instead:

```
if (w == 1) {
    System.out.println("1");
} else if (w == 2) {
    System.out.println("2");
} else if (w == 3) {
    System.out.println("3p");
} else if (w == 4) {
    System.out.println("4");
} else {
    System.out.println("csd");
}
```

**But**: Once <s>[JEP 325](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325)</s> [JEP 354](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) is supported, you'll be able to use a `switch` *expression* instead:

```
switch (w) {
    case 1 ->  System.out.println("1");
    case 2 ->  System.out.println("2");
    case 3 ->  System.out.println("3p");
    case 4 ->  System.out.println("4");
    default -> System.out.println("csd");
}
```

JEP 325 is a [preview feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12) in JDK 12.0.2 and JEP 354 (a slight update to it) is a preview feature in JDK 13. You can compile code using it like this:

```
javac --enable-preview --release 13 Example.java
```

and run it like this:

```
java --enable-preview --release 13 Example
```

Use release 13 for JEP 325 and 14 for JEP 354.

In addition to the usage above, the interesting thing about `switch` expressions is that they're *expressions* resulting in a value. See the JEP for details.

Comment: Although I have the latest Java, it says: "Case Labels with '->' is a preview feature and disabled by default. Use --enable-preview to enable". I enabled it but still it didn't work.

Comment: @user148382 - Thanks. I've added details for how to use it in JDK 12.0.2 and JDK 13.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way to solve your issue, by using a map for example :

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Map.of(1, "1", 2, ....);
System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(w, "csd"));
```

NOTE: The syntax of the map is from Java 9+, you can create a map with many ways.

Comment: @user148382 that syntax is from java 9 or plus, just search for the way to create a map befor java 8 and you are fine, sorry I answer wirh phone

Comment: I have the latest version.

Comment: @user148382 If you have the last version then it should work, even the first answer ;)

Comment: @YCF_L - :-) If by "first answer" you mean mine, turns out they had to preview it in JDK 13 as well. Got some feedback that pushed it back a release.